# Authenticated users can't view the front page

Tags: 6, users

I set `node/4` as the front page on the Site Information screen.

This works for anonymous users, but authenticated users cannot access the front page (node/4).  Even if they manually type `www.site.com`, they are redirected to `www.site.com/user/4`.

Please help me out.

Comment: You probably have a redirect set somewhere.  First, change to the default theme (Bartik/Garland).  If that doesn't fix it, start disabling contrib modules one by one.  When you know which module/theme is causing the problem and if you still can't fix it yourself, edit your question and someone should be able to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue: I am using `drupal_render('user_login')` inside a template, which is redirecting to a "user/%" page, once the user is logged-in.

Answer (score 0):

Building on Patrick Kenny's comment, I'd recommend looking for the 'URL redirects' page within your admin pages. (You will have this page if you've installed a module which supports URL redirects - 'Redirect' in D7, 'Path redirect' in D6.) Then see if any rule is defined there which'd redirect visitors from site.com/node/4 to site.com/user/4 .

If this module isn't doing this, odds are another one is, so as Patrick says start disabling contrib modules one by one.